# Why can't I get a input.value in this case?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a input.value through this code. Stored the value in

```
const inputName
```

```
const target = document.querySelector(".attend");
const inputName = document.getElementById("input")
const attendee = document.getElementById("attendee");

function attend() {
  attendee.textContent = inputName.value

}
target.addEventListener('click', attend);
```

But this code cannot get a input.value

The below code works.

```
const target = document.querySelector(".attend");
const inputName = document.getElementById("input").value
const attendee = document.getElementById("attendee");

function attend(inputName) {
  attendee.textContent = inputName
}
```

The difference between first code and second code are

```
const inputName = document.getElementById("input")

const inputName = document.getElementById("input").value
```

I want to get a input.value in 'attend()' function like this use first code

```
const inputName = document.getElementById("input")
```

```
function attend(inputName) {
  attendee.textContent = inputName.value
}
```

but when I check the value through console.log().

It didn't get the input.values.

Is it matter of global, local variable? or other reason?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Answer (score 0):

Both examples work fine for me, I think that your issue might be that the element is being removed or changed somehow before you get the value.